# Edit New Products Title Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

In my home i added a widget for new products but i want to rename new products to something else[image]`

Answer (score 0):

Go to widget phtml file( using path hint), Change title in the file or while adding widget in back end admin dashboard, change the title.